# How to delete all KDevelop generated files?

Tags: file, kdevelop

I've been trying to browse a big codebase with KDevelop. I had to give up that but KDevelop has managed to generate 3GB of data in the project folder as a result of background parse. I want to delete all that is left of KDevelop as that project is in a virtual machine with little space. I just don't know where to look for files, even though they are so big.

Answer (score 5):

The right way to clear cache is starting KDevelop this way:

```
CLEAR_DUCHAIN_DIR=1 kdevelop
```

Comment: Yeah, well some of us have more than one session. Some of us more than 10! I think you mean `CLEAR_DUCHAIN_DIR=1 kdevelop --pick-session` or even `CLEAR_DUCHAIN_DIR=1 kdevelop --open-session "{UID}"`?

Also, THANK YOU! :D

Answer (score 2):

Got an answer yesterday on KDevelop IRC. The generated files are somewhere unders ~/.cache so I have deleted the directory alltogether. With older KDevelop one has ~/.kdevuchain something but that's deprecated these days

Comment: Just to clarify: It's `~/.cache/kdevduchain` nowadays; `~/.kdevduchain` for older versions of KDevelop